# Integrate CKEditor autolink plugin in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I was trying to add [AutoLink](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/tree/major/plugins/autolink) plugin for CKEditor in my rails application,
I tried following this steps
1. Inside vendor/assets/javascripts/ckeditor I created a folder plugins/autolink and kept the [plugin.js](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/plugins/autolink/plugin.js) file from github
2. Then added the following below code to vendor/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js file

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
  ...
  config.extraPlugins = 'autolink';
  ...
};
```

but when i restarted my server it was showing following error message

```
    ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/ckeditor/plugins/textmatch/plugin.js"):

    actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
    web-console (3.6.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
    web-console (3.6.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
    web-console (3.6.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
    web-console (3.6.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
    actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
    railties (5.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
    railties (5.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
    activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
    activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
    railties (5.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:11:in `block in call'
    activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/logger_silence.rb:20:in `silence'
    activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/logger.rb:63:in `block (3 levels) in broadcast'
    activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/logger_silence.rb:20:in `silence'
    activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/logger.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in broadcast'
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:11:in `call'
    actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
    rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
    rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
    activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
    actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
    actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
    rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
    railties (5.0.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
    puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
    puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
    puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
    puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
    puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

please tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The Autolink plugin, is dependent on Textmatch plugin, which is not present. So adding that solved the issue.